# TransformError react native 0.7.1

Tags: react-native, babeljs

when i build my react-native application using Xcode and launch it, the emulator shows the error red screen with the following message:

`TransformError: /path/to/app/index.ios.js: /path/to/app/index.ios.js: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined]
  message: 'TransformError: /path/to/app/index.ios.js: /path/to/app/index.ios.js: Cannot read property \'line\' of undefined',`

I've built one application a month ago with react-native v 0.4.x and i've never had this message.

I've tried with node 0.12 and different versions of iojs

I'm using react-native v0.7.1 and xCode v6.4

The project is totally empty of any code wrote by me, i just:

$ react-native init reactNat (with react-native-cli v0.1.4)

I read that now react-native is directly integrated with babel and I suppose the problem came from that but with no more clues.

If anybody have an idea it would be very nice!

Thanks guys

Comment: I think that the users would be most graceful if you could add the code snippet causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use node.js >= 4.0, as per [the 'getting started' guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install multiple node versions on your system.